# Convert a string containing html tags to .jpg in php

Tags: php, html

Is there any way to convert a string containing html tags into an image format where the tags will convert to desired output ans display the html elements as can be displayed in an html web page using php?
The variable containing the html code may be as follows:
 `

```
$Message="<html>
                <body>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                           <td> Name:</td><td>Varsha Das</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Phone No.</td><td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        </tr>
                     </table>
                  </body>
           </html>";
```

` 
This is a variable of the message body of the email i am sending to my user and this thus gets rendered to them as html table. I wish to send the same over to the user in a non editable format. be it image or pdf. So i have to use any kind of function that will render the html and convert it into pdf or image. The server is running on XAMPP. Please Help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use image gd library.

Comment: Don't know about pure php solution, but you can run [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html).

Comment: I have seen the manual of GD library but if you could send me the link where they have implemented html texts, then it would be a great help. since i could not find it.

Comment: Thanks @HonzaHaering Will try and let you know.

Comment: Are you looking for `imagefttext` ?  : http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefttext.php

Comment: Try converting html to `canvas` and then save canvas as image using `javascript`.

Comment: Mahendra, I cannot use such method since this is all done by one php file, I have say a file named myPHPMail.php, which is sending emails with content type html from the data that I am fetching from database. Then I am to send this data through email. 
Makesh, Thanks for the link. hope this works.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but this is not working. The file is displaying an error message and a black web page is appearing which has got no image.